# unable to use nvidia graphics in lxc container after upgrade to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, lxc

I have upgraded my system from 15.10 to 16.04 and the container from 14.04 to 16.04.

I have used the default cuda/nvidia driver in both. cuda 7.5 and nvidia 361.42

When I start the container I get the lightdm DM. I cannot move the mouse or use the keyboard. 16.04 is missing the kbd and mouse modules. Any ideas how to fix that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The proprietary NVIDIA driver that comes with 16.04 seems to be problematic. I had problems with it, and I've seen at least one other question complaining of problems. This is what I did to solve my issue; it should work for you.

1. Enter a TTY by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. Log in with your username and password.
3. Run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` and confirm any prompts.
4. Run `sudo apt-add repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and then `sudo apt-get update`.
5. Run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-364`.

This will install the latest driver from that repository/PPA. It is a newer version than the one that comes with Ubuntu (361.42 vs. 364.15) and seems to be a bit more stable. It's also open source, so that's a plus **;-)**.

If you have any problems, or are confused by these instructions, leave a comment.

Comment: I followed your direction. The display is now working, but I have no mouse or keyboard control.  I think ubuntu 16.04 is missing the xorg-kdb module. Any suggestion.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get purge xorg-* xserver-xorg || sudo apt-get install xorg xserver-xorg`. This might make it worse, so be careful.

Comment: I have tried it. I do not have mouse or keyboard control. There is something else that is missing. the kbd and mouse packages are not available  for ubuntu 16.04, Do I need to remove  the evdev package. i.e xserver-xorg-input-evdev. If I do that what is the alternative for keyboard and mouse.

Comment: @user63726 I don't know about that

Comment: I was able to get the 16.04 lxc container to have graphics (with functioning mouse and keyboard) I am not able to get graphics with lxc 14.04.3 container.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen because xorg inputs in your container where configured using `xserver-xorg-input-kbd`, which is dropped in 16.04. In this case you could solve this by reconfiguring the inputs using evdev. You can find, more information in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/879020/649426).